# compass compile under www-data user

Tags: nginx, rvm, compass

I need to compile scss by `www-data` user from nginx/php5-fpm

command:

```
compass compile sass/screen.scss --config config.rb --boring
```

result:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
    from /usr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

**UPD1**

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
compass (1.1.0.alpha.3, 1.0.1)
compass-core (1.1.0.alpha.3, 1.0.1)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the compass gem is not installed. try running

```
gem install compass
```

Comment: is it also installed / available for the www-data user? maybe www-data uses a different ruby version and different gems? does the gem list cmd run as www-data return a list containing compass?